# javascript not responding

Tags: javascript

In my webapp I am receiving this message:

> "A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can
>   stop the script now".

What should I do?

Comment: what is your script doing? does it have loops?

Comment: You should stop the script now.

Answer (score 1):

That generally means that you have a script that is stuck in an infinite loop. Stop the script and take a look at your javascript to see what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers have built in developer tools which will aid you in debugging your script.  Use those tools to figure out why your script is behaving incorrectly.

Comment: I don't know if he is using IE.  But, if he is, I've provided concrete steps on how to open the Developer Tools in IE.

Comment: Actually, that is the mozilla message. Each browser has a different message.

Comment: sorry, but you are not answering anything here - just reporing the fact, that IE has developer tools.. and yes, firefox and chrome have them too

Comment: @fazo:  I apologize.  The intent of my answer is to encourage the OP to use the developer tools in the browser to debug the script.  I'll update my answer accordingly.